How we can check request source for Azure APIM
In Application insights got some exceptions related to APIM but request source is unknown, please refer the screens below.


Is there any way we can trace out or come to know how to get request source/ from which service APIM get called.
Way we can trace out or come to know how to get request source/ from which service APIM get called.

I have enabled Application Insight in APIM in the following way-





Then I invoked Echo API and a function app which was imported to APIM.
You can identify the request by using the sdk version as well.
I am getting below log for Echo API.



Logs for function app.


